# What is the difference between prependClientTransformer and appendClientTransformer in Symfony2 form?

Tags: symfony

What is the difference between prependClientTransformer and appendClientTransformer in Symfony2 form? When should I use prependClientTransformer, appendClientTransformer. Any examples?

Answer (score 3):

What I've understood about this :

The FormType you're applying the DataTransformer to has a parent Type defined in getParent() method.

**prependClientTransformer** will apply passed DataTransformer **BEFORE** those ones that are applied from parent Type.

**appendClientTransformer** will apply passed DataTransformer **AFTER** those ones that are applied from parent Type.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the [source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php#L374) these methods are used to control the calling sequence of the `clientTransformers` which are used for transform the field data. It is useful when you create custom field type.

For example you want to create a `tag` field type which will take comma separated values which will internally transformed to array of tags. You set its parent as `text` field type. You also created a transformer for tag type which transforms array to string or vice-versa. Now your tag type will have two `clientTranformer`, [ValueToStringTransFormer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ValueToStringTransformer.php) and your transformer at last position. So when you bind data to a form or submit the form symfony will transform the client data to string and convert the transformed string then to array (as described [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L1056)). And for reverse case it will transform the array to string and then string to client value (as defined [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L1076)). Haven't found a use case for `prependClientTransformer` though :).