# What is appendNormTransformer in the Symfony FormBuilder?

Tags: symfony

What is appendNormTransformer in the Symfony FormBuilder? When should I use this instead of appendClientTransformer and prependClientTransformer

Comment: For the difference, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210347/what-is-the-difference-between-prependclienttransformer-and-appendclienttransfor

Comment: He is the one who asked this question ;)

Comment: @Matt lol, didn't notice that, sorry :D

Comment: Hehe np, just found the fact funny :)

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the class documentation block of [Form.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php):

```
To implement your own form fields, you need to have a thorough understanding
of the data flow within a form field. A form field stores its data in three
different representations:

 (1) the format required by the form's object
 (2) a normalized format for internal processing
 (3) the format used for display

A date field, for example, may store a date as "Y-m-d" string (1) in the
object. To facilitate processing in the field, this value is normalized
to a DateTime object (2). In the HTML representation of your form, a
localized string (3) is presented to and modified by the user.
```

So `(1)` is the app data, `(2)` is the normalized data and `(3)` is the client data.

Now, for your question, it depends which data would like to transform. If is the client data you need to transform (from `(2)` to `(3)`), then you should use `appendClientTransformer` or `prependClientTransformer`.

On the opposite, if you would like to change the normalized data (from `(1)` to `(2)`), then you should use `appendNormTransformer` or `prependNormTransformer`.

So, normalization transformer sits between `(1)` and `(2)` (`(1)` normalizeTransformer -> `(2)`). And client transformer sits between `(2)` and `(3)` (`(2)` clientTransformer -> `(3)`)

Also, note that append and prepend methods ([append|prepend][Norm|Client]Transformer) will potentially be replaced by a add methods (add[Norm|Client]Transformer) in Symfony 2.1, see [this pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3855) on GitHub for more information.

Hope this helps,
Matt